# Typo3 website. When surfing around the site sometimes the browser shows the html code instead of showing the site

Tags: html, typo3

I have a Typo3 website (version 4.5.32). Sometimes (randomly) when I'm surfing around my website the browser shows the html code instead of showing the webpage.

For example it shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 11:36:29 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=f4b8445b0719bd7490dcde98e7d8ff5b;
path=/; domain=.<my_domain>
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

bfee
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html>
<!-- Cached page generated 12-02-15 12:35. Expires 13-02-15 12:35 -->
<!-- Parsetime: 0ms -->
0
```

when it should show the webpage.

Another example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 11:41:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=fd0199b1f48b719c097ef19418f18397; path=/; domain=.<my_domain>
Expires: 0
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 11:41:19 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: be_typo_user=71e6061cabf0d60a03739493561b67d9; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

9395
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html>
<!-- Cached page generated 12-02-15 12:37. Expires 13-02-15 12:37 -->
<!-- Parsetime: 111ms -->
0
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there are extra characters before your actual websites HTML. Please check this.

Comment: Might be your site build in TemplaVoila templating method. You need to check your server configuration for TYPO3: https://typo3.org/typo3-cms/overview/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

The extra character before the actual output (bfee, 9395) are the lengths of the following block of data. The header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` also indicates that the output is cut into blocks (chunks).

All user agents (browsers, etcetera) must support chunked transfer encoding. Perhaps there is some proxy in between that ruins the experience? Anyway, it's the webserver that decides to use this transfer encoding and not TYPO3.
The only thing inside TYPO3 that could ruin things is when the content is retrieved using `t3lib_div::getUrl()`. This function only supports chunked data if you have cURL activated in the installation.